# Netbeans 7: Why is my edited manifest not being included?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, manifest, netbeans-7

I have the following target in my `build.xml`:

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <buildnumber file="build.version"/>
    <tstamp>
        <format property="timestamp" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
    </tstamp>
    <manifest file="manifest.mf">
        <attribute name="MAJOR" value="${version.major}"/>
        <attribute name="MINOR" value="${version.minor}"/>
        <attribute name="RELEASE" value="${release}"/>
        <attribute name="BUILD" value="${build.number}"/>
        <attribute name="BUILD-DATE" value="${timestamp}"/>
        <attribute name="PROTOCOL" value="${protocol}"/>
        <attribute name="APPCODE" value="${appcode}"/>
    </manifest>    
</target>
```

It works fine, opening `manifest.mf` after a Clean and Build within Netbeans shows all my extra attributes that I've added. However, when I open my jar file I see that it just contains the default stuff:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0-b147 (Oracle Corporation)
```

I had this working fine before when I had two packages in one project. The one package was all library stuff that I'm gonna be taking to other projects, so I decided to split it out into another project so I could build the library jar by itself. Now I have this problem. It occurs both when I compile the library on its own as well as my other project that depends on it.

Comment: Where's that part that builds the jar file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed it by opening `nbproject/project.properties` and adding `manifest.file=manifest.mf` to the end. Simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

check this answer here: [Is it possible to add a custom manifest to a Java library compiled in Netbeans 6.7.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598229/is-it-possible-to-add-a-custom-manifest-to-a-java-library-compiled-in-netbeans-6)

I had your same problem, adding this at the end of my build.xml solved the issue:

```
<target name="-post-jar">
 <jar destfile="${dist.jar}" update="true">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0" />           
        <attribute name="Extension-Name" value="polpol" />
        <attribute name="Class-Manager" value="org.nlogo.extensions.polpol.Manager" />
        <attribute name="NetLogo-Extension-API-Version" value="5.0" />
    </manifest>
 </jar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have encountered the same issues youre having here, and luckly enough have fixed it. Unfortunately I dont know what exactly caused the issue, and after comparing your code to mine, the only difference I see really is the name of the manifest file in your build.xml, and the event which triggers the task (I used pre init). I have all in capitals, and supplement the manifest version info with in the Version.txt file which is created in the dist directory -post-jar. You may just want to try to make

manifest file="manifest.mf"

read

manifest file="MANIFEST.MF"

Here is a copy of the important parts of my build.xml:

```
<property name="project.name" value="VOXManagement" /> 
    <property name="version.num" value="1.1" /> 
    <target name="-pre-init"> 
       <tstamp> 
          <format property="NOW" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z" /> 
       </tstamp> 
       <manifest file="MANIFEST.MF"> 
          <attribute name="Bundle-Name" value="${project.name}" />            
          <attribute name="Bundle-Version" value="${version.num}" /> 
          <attribute name="Bundle-Date" value="${NOW}" /> 
          <!--<attribute name="Bundle-Revision" value="${svna.version}" />-->
          <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${project.name}" /> 
          <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${version.num}" /> 
       </manifest>  
       <echo file="Version.txt">V${version.num}</echo>     
    </target>
    <target name="-post-jar">
        <copy file="Version.txt" todir="dist" overwrite="true"/>    
        <delete file="dist/README.TXT"/>
    </target>
```

Comment: I tried using caps (on windows where pathnames are case insensitive) and that didn't work, and I tried moving it to -pre-init and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "update mode".

`<manifest file="${manifest.file}" mode="update">`

Comment: Didn't work either. Like I said in my OP, if I run clean and build and open the manifest afterwards I can see that the manifest has all my fields in it, but it seems they get removed or my manifest is replaced when the jar-ing takes place.

Comment: Maybe a new manifest is being created (not updated) before NetBeans script creating the jar. Maybe put your `manifest` task in `-pre-jar` target.

Comment: I'm sure I've tried that too but I will try again later when I get home from work.

Answer (score 1):

As Thihara already asked, you may have a task that builds the jar? 
are you having manifest="MANIFEST.MF" in your create jar(or something similary ) tag/task?

```
<target name="jar">
        <jar   manifest="path-to/MANIFEST.MF" basedir="base dir" destfile="outJarfileName">
        </jar>
    </target>
```

Comment: I haven't edited any of netbeans' tasks or anything, I've just done the usual override of the target in `build.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

While Creating Jars,Wars,Ears a common issue in MANIFEST.MF is

**"Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_40-b43 (Oracle Corporation)"**

If you want to Ignore Ant-Version Number and Created by use filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain" option.

```
<jar destfile="MyJar.jar" basedir="./bin" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain"  manifest="./src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" update="true" >
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Netbeans 7.3.X**
for **.war**
in the build.xml Use

```
<manifest file="${build.web.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">...</manifest>
```